# Всегда ли оправдан(н)о наказание?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Объясните, какой вариант правильный:

1. *Преступление и наказание. Всегда ли оправдано наказание?*
2. *Преступление и наказание. Всегда ли оправданно наказание?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Попробуем выбрать вариант: Всегда ли оправдаННо наказание?

Действуем по инструкции:

Из словаря: **оправданный**; кр. ф. прич. -ан, -ана; кр. ф. прил. -ан, -ана **(с дополн.**: оправданы важностью проекта) и -ан, -анна (**без дополн**.: его действия вполне оправданны; ваше беспокойство оправданно).

Дополнения нет? Значит, пишем две буквы НН.

2) Но в "Нацкорпусе частотность выше у "оправдано" (440:220), при этом на дополнение, кажется, никто не смотрит.

Примеры: Использование однолетних цветов вполне оправдано. Заимствование технологий далеко не всегда оправданно.

3) Использование причастной формы с одной буквой Н понятно, так как глагол "оправдать" многозначен, и одно из значений: ОПРАВДАТЬ, 3. что (чем). Признать что-л. допустимым, возможным, непредосудительным.

Поэтому мы говорим:  всегда ли можно оправдать наказание? Тогда: Всегда ли оправдано наказание? Наказание не всеми приветствуется, поэтому оправдывать его надо каким-то доводами (чем-то), а это уже ближе к причастию.

4) В общем, задача имеет два решения с разными оттенками смысла (оправданно и оправдано): (1) Всегда ли допустимо наказание? (2) Всегда ли можно оправдать наказание?